# xmobar does not appear on top of window stack when xmonad starts

Tags: xmonad

I'm experiencing a strange behaviour of `xmobar` right after i enter `xmonad`.  When i `xmonad` (from `.xinitrc`, i use XDM) my `xmobar` appears but **it is not either at the top or bottom of the window stack**.  Once i start an application (e.g. terminal emulator by pressing `Mod + Shift + Return`) the application uses the entire screen, as if the `xmobar` was at the bottom.  Then i press `Mod + B` and nothing happens, once i press `Mod + B` a second time `xmobar` is lifted to the top reducing the application window size.

After that `Mod + B` works correctly for the remainder of the `xmonad` session, i.e. it lowers/raises (hides/shows) the `xmobar`.

I'm confident i misconfigured something.  My `xmonad.hs` looks like:

```
import XMonad
import XMonad.Hooks.SetWMName
import XMonad.Hooks.DynamicLog

main = do
  xmonad =<< statusBar "xmobar" myPP toggleStrutsKey defaultConfig
    { terminal           = "urxvt"
    , focusFollowsMouse  = True
    , clickJustFocuses   = False
    , borderWidth        = 1
    , modMask            = mod4Mask
    , workspaces         = myworkspaces
    , normalBorderColor  = "#dddddd"
    , focusedBorderColor = "#00dd00"
    , manageHook         = mymanager
    , startupHook        = setWMName "LG3D"
    }

myPP = xmobarPP { ppOutput          = putStrLn
                , ppCurrent         = xmobarColor "#336433" "" . wrap "[" "]"
                --, ppHiddenNoWindows = xmobarColor "grey" ""
                , ppTitle           = xmobarColor "darkgreen"  "" . shorten 20
                , ppLayout          = shorten 6
                --, ppVisible         = wrap "(" ")"
                , ppUrgent          = xmobarColor "red" "yellow"
                }

toggleStrutsKey XConfig { XMonad.modMask = modMask } = (modMask, xK_b)

myworkspaces = [ "code"
               , "web"
               , "media"
               , "irc"
               , "random"
               , "mail"
               , "docs"
               , "music"
               , "root"
               ]

mymanager = composeAll
  [ className =? "gimp" --> doFloat
  , className =? "vlc"  --> doFloat
  ]
```

Whilst the beginning of my `.xmobarrc` looks as follows:

```
Config {
  -- appearance
    font =         "xft:Bitstream Vera Sans Mono:size=9:bold:antialias=true"
  , bgColor =      "black"
  , fgColor =      "#646464"
  , position =     Top
  , border =       BottomB
  , borderColor =  "#646464"

  -- layout
  , sepChar =  "%"   -- delineator between plugin names and straight text
  , alignSep = "}{"  -- separator between left-right alignment
  , template = "%battery% | %multicpu% | %coretemp% | %memory% | %dynnetwork% | %StdinReader% }{ %date% || %kbd% "

  -- general behavior
  , lowerOnStart =     False   -- send to bottom of window stack on start
  , hideOnStart =      False   -- start with window unmapped (hidden)
  , allDesktops =      True    -- show on all desktops
  , overrideRedirect = True    -- set the Override Redirect flag (Xlib)
  , pickBroadest =     False   -- choose widest display (multi-monitor)
  , persistent =       True    -- enable/disable hiding (True = disabled)

  -- plugins (i do not use any)

  , commands = [  -- actually several commands are in here
  ]
}
```

I tried several combinations of:

```
, lowerOnStart =
, hideOnStart =
```

(True/True, True/False, False/True and False/False as shown now).  But the behaviour before i press `Mod + B` two times does not change.  I believe that i have misconfigured `xmonad` in some way not `xmobar` but that is just a guess.

My `.xinitrc` might be of help:

```
#!/bin/sh

if test -d /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d
then
    # /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d is actually empty
    for f in /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d/*
    do
        [ -x "$f" ] && source "$f"
    done
    unset f
fi

# uk keyboard
setxkbmap gb

xrdb .Xresources
xscreensaver -no-splash &

# java behaves badly in non-reparenting window managers (e.g. xmonad)
export _JAVA_AWT_WM_NONREPARENTING=1

# set the background (again, because qiv uses a different buffer)
/usr/bin/feh --bg-scale --no-fehbg -z /usr/share/archlinux/wallpaper/a*.jpg

# pulse audio for alsa
then
    /usr/bin/start-pulseaudio-x11
fi

exec xmonad
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Two months later I figured it out.  The problem is that `statusBar` does not register the events of `Hooks.manageDocks` properly.  Once `xmonad` is running all works well because `manageDocks` is able to update the `Struts` on every window event.  But in the moment that `xmonad` is starting the event of making the first windows fullscreen happens before the events from `manageDocks`.  This mages that first open window to ignore the existence of `xmobar`.

`manageDocks` has its event handler that **must** be set as the last event handler, therefore `statusBar` cannot be used.  Instead, it is necessary to make `xmonad` call and configure `xmobar` manually through `dynamicLog`, `manageHook`, `layoutHook` and `handleEventHook`.  A minimalistic configuration for this would be:

```
main = do
    xmproc <- spawnPipe "xmobar"
    xmonad $ defaultConfig
      { modMask            = mod4Mask
      , manageHook         = manageDocks <+> manageHook defaultConfig
      , layoutHook         = avoidStruts  $ layoutHook defaultConfig
      -- this must be in this order, docksEventHook must be last
      , handleEventHook    = handleEventHook defaultConfig <+> docksEventHook
      , logHook            = dynamicLogWithPP xmobarPP
          { ppOutput          = hPutStrLn xmproc
          , ppTitle           = xmobarColor "darkgreen"  "" . shorten 20
          , ppHiddenNoWindows = xmobarColor "grey" ""
          }
      , startupHook        = setWMName "LG3D"
      } `additionalKeys`
      [ ((mod4Mask, xK_b), sendMessage ToggleStruts) ]
```

This makes all events to be processed by `docsEventHook` and ensures that layout changes made by `docsEventHook` are the last ones applied.  Now

```
lowerOnStart = False
```

(or `True`) works as expected *in all cases* within `xmobarrc`.

Comment: You may as well use `statusBar` and just overwrite the `handleEventHook = handleEventHook defaultConfig <+> docksEventHook` until the DynamicLog package is fixed.

Comment: in the latest version of xmonad-contrib package, `docksEventHook` is in `XMonad.Hooks.ManageDocks` https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.16/docs/XMonad-Hooks-ManageDocks.html

Comment: @rudolph9 - You are correct.  Although I'm avoiding to do a bump just to add the extra import - moreover since then I should probably change `defaultConfig` to `XMonad.Config.def` :) and other bits that would probably become more of a clutter.

Answer (score 2):

Comparing your config, to my simpler one, which does work correctly in this regard, I see one difference that might do something:

from all the `general behaviour` options you have I only have

```
lowerOnStart = True
```

and not a single of `hideOnStart`, `overrideRedirect` etc.

The way you add xmobar in `xmonad.hs` is, as far as I can read, the same as mine.

In this case I'd try with as much default settings as possible, e.g. rename `.xmobarrc` so it's not picked up, and change `xmonad.hs` to e.g.

```
main = xmonad =<< statusBar "xmobar" xmobarPP toggleStrutsKey defaultConfig
toggleStrutsKey XConfig { XMonad.modMask = modMask } = (modMask, xK_b)
```

and see if it works. Later add bit by bit, and see when it breaks.

Comment: Thanks, your answer reminded me that I should debug it starting from an empty `xmonad.hs`.  That made me find the actual problem :)